# Why does the Breeze Web API implementation respond to metadata requests with a string instead of a JSON object?

Tags: breeze

Is there any reason that the Breeze Web API implementation of the response to any metadata requests [returns a string](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html) instead of a JSON object?

Sending metadata as text adds a lot of overhead over the network (due " encoding) and on clientside due manual JSON.parse.

I think that your [controller](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller) can simply return the Metadata as JSON by specifying the contentType header:
i.e.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Metadata()
{
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(_contextProvider.Metadata())};
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: It's a good idea, we are looking at implementing something similar for the next release while trying to avoid breaking any existing code. Please keep up the input on stuff like this. It really improves the product. I will post back here once this has happened.

Comment: Hi @JayTraband, I converted your answer to a comment so John is aware of it.  The question could really use some context as well.  It's not clear what's being asked here.  If one of you could clarify the question itself, we can reopen it to be answered.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I just edited the original question into "submission".  I hope this is adequate.

Comment: Changed the title as well to make it clear this is a question about how Breeze implements Web API and if there are reasons it cannot use JSON.

Comment: @John - would you hyperlink to a suitable reference to Breeze API in your question? I should think most people don't know what this is, but might be interested in taking a look if you make it easy to do so.

Comment: @halfer - Thank you. Just added links to both the API and the Web API docs.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next release (v.1.2.6?)

Answer (score 1):

As of v 1.2.7, the **BreezeController** attribute now does this automatically.... and thanks for the idea.