# Why does Web API BreezeController return XML formatted Metadata?

Tags: breeze, asp.net-web-api

I've created a web api controller using Breeze server.  I'm using .NET 4.5 and EF6 (database first).  Here are the relevant packages I loaded from Nuget:

```
<package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider" version="1.5.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Breeze.Server.ContextProvider.EF6" version="1.5.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Breeze.Server.WebApi2" version="1.5.4" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I'm finding that my metadata is being returned as an XML formatted string and not JSON.  As a result, my client cannot consume the metadata response.  Here's a snippet of the controller's code:

```
[BreezeController]
[EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:9000", "*", "*")]
public class CoreController : ApiController
{

    private readonly EFContextProvider<MyModel> _contextProvider = 
        new EFContextProvider<MyModel>();

    public CoreController(){ }

    [HttpGet]
    public string MetaData()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata(); 
    }
```

When I make a call to the MetaData end point using Postman, I get the following returned:

```
"{\"?xml\":{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"encoding\":\"utf-8\"},\"schema\":{\"namespace\":\"MytModel\",...
```

I know there was a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494117/breeze-metadata-appears-in-xml-format), but that seemed to be related to the breeze client.  In my case, the breeze web api enabled controller is returning the data in this fashion.  I also noticed someone make a similar comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507497/why-does-the-breeze-web-api-implementation-respond-to-metadata-requests-with-a-s), but the answer was that the [BreezeController] attribute should address this.  I'm using the BreezeController attribute as noted above, but still no luck.  Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thank You